# PHP mail- a specific from address- the email never arrives

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I am using PHP to send emails using mail.
Now I am sending it with a from address being my domain. This works fine when sending from any email address @ said domain (such as abc@domain.com, fff@domain.com), but their is 1 certain address that just doesnt work.

When I send it from the email reports@domain.com (which is an email account that exists), the error logs look fine, but the email never arrives. Not in spam or anything.

Why would it be that a certain from email address is failing? I'm not sure if this is a problem with sendmail or PHP.

I've checked the settings of the reports email account and they all look the same as every other account that does work so im not sure where to start looking.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Reverse DNS, SPF and Domain Keys of your mail server and your domain

Utilize the followings #

- [Debouncer](http://www.debouncer.com/reverse-dns-check)
- [MXToolBox](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/)
- [intoDNS](http://www.intodns.com)

Comment: Everything looks fine. Reverse PTR record is installed and resolves correctly. Why would it be a DNS issue though if its only 1 address on the same domain that will not work? No bounceback or refusal from the mail server- just simply never arrives.

Comment: Please provide your sender and receiver domain name here, it will helpful for us for better debugging

Comment: Please check the receiver domain's credentials and records.